# How do I restore a calendar in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I deleted a calendar but I need it back now. I don't know how to restore it.

I see it in the deleted items but it has no restore button or anything in that nature. I tried to drag it to the calendar area but it won't let me.

Comment: Are you in "Folder List" view?

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking at the deleted items in 'folder list' view there are 2 ways in which you can restore the calender from there.

Firstly you can simply 'right click' on the item you want restored and select 'move folder'

[image: First Option]

The second option is dragging from the 'deleted items' folder to the destination that you would like to store it - (i see that you have tried this, but i would recommend trying it again, but 'right clicking' and moving) You will then be asked if you would like to either 'move' or 'copy' the file

[image: Second Option]

Hope this information is of some help to you :)